# SSH connection using proxy instead of port forwarding

Tags: linux, ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel, vnc

I have a linux system behind a network where I cannot do port forwarding

Is it possible to configure my SSH and VNCserver on the machine to use a proxy server from which i can make vnc and ssh connection to the machine instead?

**Example:**

**Machine A** is behind network where port forwarding is not allowed and contains VNC server and SSH that i need to access

**Machine B** allows port forwarding , also have proxy server hosted

I want to access VNC server on Machine A using VNC viewer but since port forwarding is not allowed i cannot connect.

I want to know if there is a way to use Machine B ( some kind of piggy backing method ) to access vnc server on Machine A

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a ssh jump host would be a solution in this case?
The other solution is to have a shell account on some server and connect to it like below:

```
ssh -D 1025 login@your-ssh-server-ip-address
```

Example:

```
ssh -D 1025 user@192.168.0.1
```

Then you have to open a port tcp/1025 on a firewall to be able to listen on it.

Then open Firefox, go to 
    ->Edit->Preferences, tab Advanced->Network,

```
field Connection, 
button Settings.
```

Choose "Manual proxy configuration",

in field "SOCKS Host" type

```
localhost
```

and

```
port 1025,
```

choose SOCKS v5.

And this way you have a fully encrypted connection.

Comment: I am sorry but i dont understand how this helps , since if commands are just jumping using jump server it will stil require ssh server on the machine where i cannot do port forwarding , also is your method only allowing firefox traffic only?

Comment: ProgNi describe then the configuration, because your question is not quite clear. I can try to understand how to solve your issue, because you wrote that you can use ssh, but cannot do port forwarding. Then just go through the tunnel on port 80 using SSH , because port 80 is by default open port for HTTP traffic. Eventually you can try to use 443 port for HTTPS. It is really hard to understand the question without the knowledge about your configuration - I mean a graph.

Comment: If you want to use a proxy , this also can be done on your machine. I do not understand why do you want to use VNC. Can you make a graph with description for us, please? Maybe someone will be able to help, including me.

Comment: I have edited my question with an example scenario which hopefully will explain the issue , also i cannot access SSH or VNC , I need to access both without port forwarding

Comment: Now I know what do you mean. It is late, but I will try to answer tomorrow. I must rethink it first.

Comment: ProgNi does machine A allows connections on port 80? Can you try to connect through ssh from machine B to machine A using port 80? Like ssh usernameonmachineA@IPaddressoftheAmachine -p 80. example ssh debian@192.168.0.10 -p 80.

Comment: No unfortunately Machine A network does not allow incoming network on any port , that is the reason i want to use a proxy server instead

Comment: I see. This is strange. So you are not able to even manage firewall rules on machine A. If it drops packets, then how do you want to be able to connect to it via proxy, if all incoming connections will be rejected?

Comment: Well i can access Machine A at its localhost location so i can change firewall rules but since the machine is on network where port forwarding is not allowed i cannot provide it port for incoming connections , Proxy server is hosted on Machine B though

Comment: Is it possible to connect to VNC port to machine A for example 5900? 
Can you scan the network where machine A is located for open ports?

Comment: As i have mentioned i cannot connect to any port , just to clarify i have to be able to access Machine a VNC and SSH through different network and Machine A network does not allow port fording

Comment: If machine A is totally isolated and there is no way to conenct to it, there is no possibility to conenct to this machine. Machine A should be able to connect to other machine in its local area network for example to machine C, and from machine C you can jump outside if it is possible of course. If machine A and hypothetic machine C are in the same LAN , which is isolated (no connection with the Internet) than there is no possibility to connect to machine A. You have to answer one question, does the network , where machine A is located has any connection with the Internet.

Comment: Machine A can be connected using teamviewer etc, the issue is just that it is not allowed to do portforwarding in network so that outside traffic can connect to it using specified port

Comment: So if TeamViewer is able to connect it has to be at least one opened port on machine A .You can use this open port to make a tunnel. Log to machine A via TeamViewer and check which ports are open on this machine and try use one of this port.

Comment: Just checked it seems that port 5938 is opened which is being used by teamviewer for connection , so how can i use this port to connect to both ssh and VNCviewer at the same time?

Comment: It depends on operating system. In linux, you have to install sshd as a service. You will find a lot of tutorials. Then you have to edit like that $ sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config and find the #Port, uncomment it and change 22 to 5938 If you use Selinux on this system, you have to add this port to Selinux with command: semanage port -d -t http_port_t -p tcp 5938. 

Then you can try to make a ssh tunnel to connect to it. 
The other option is to set up vnc server on machine a and set it to listen on this port 5938, and try to connect to machine A.

Comment: Thank you for your help i will check this method out , also according to my tests using teamviewer it seems that even after blocking teamviewer ports it seems to be working , maybe it just connects to some middle server . Also due to this i need to re-check for opened ports now since previousl yi used online port open checker tool

Comment: I made a little mistake in SELinux command: semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 5938 To remove this port from SELinux (revert back) semanage port -d -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 5938 (-a activate , -d disable).

Comment: Is there any scenario where there Machine C in the middle of Machine A and Machine B and Machine C do all the port forwarding Machine C connects to Machine A via Machine C with Machine A do not have any open port